# Separate groups of array elements separated by Nones

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I have an np.array(<>,dtype = object) of floats that are visually grouped by Nones between them. For example:

```
Event = np.array([1., 2., None, None, None, 32., 43., None], dtype = object)
```

There's no regular group-size so that it can be indexed like Event[:2:], or something of that sort. I want to separate these groups of floats into their own arrays/lists, so that I have:

```
Event_group1 = [1., 2.]
Event_group2 = [32., 43.]
```

The only solution I could think of would be to recursively sift through each element, store all floats into another list, stop storing elements once a None is reached, and then start storing elements into a new list once a float is reached again. But this is incredibly inefficient.

How would I do this in a Pythonic way?

Can't do much with the object np.array, so to start I can turn this into a boolean np.array with:

```
Event_bool = Event > 0
```

Comment: So `Event_group` could be of any size, and separated by any number of `None`?  That sounds a lot more like a list task than a `numpy` one.

Comment: @hpaulj yes to your question. And certainly can be performed as a list task. The array i'm receiving just happens to be an object np.array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Vanilla Solution

Thanks to @hilberts_drinking_problem's comment, we can see a builtin solution using itertools is as follows:

```
from itertools import groupby
x = [list(gp) for b, gp in groupby(Event, key=lambda x: x == None) if not b]
# [[1.0, 2.0], [32.0, 43.0]]
```

### Another Solution

Use [`more_itertools`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.split_at):

```
import numpy as np
from more_itertools import split_at
Event = np.array([1., 2., None, None, None, 32., 43., None], dtype = object)
x = [group for group in split_at(Event, lambda x : x == None) if group]
# [[1.0, 2.0], [32.0, 43.0]]
```

Here, we split the list at `None`s, which splits for each `None`. Thus we add `if group` to filter out empty lists from the split.

### Performance Comparison

Note that the vanilla solution is also slightly faster than the `more_itertools` version:

```
import timeit
timeit.timeit("x = [group for group in split_at(Event, lambda x : x == None) if group]",
              setup="""
import numpy as np
from more_itertools import split_at
Event = np.array([1., 2., None, None, None, 32., 43., None], dtype = object)
""", number = 1000000)
# 2.097 seconds

timeit.timeit("x = [list(gp) for b, gp in groupby(Event, key=lambda x: x == None) if not b]",
              setup="""
import numpy as np
from itertools import groupby
Event = np.array([1., 2., None, None, None, 32., 43., None], dtype = object)
""", number = 1000000)
# 1.824 seconds
```

Comment: Something similar works with builtin `itertools`: `[list(gp) for b, gp in groupby(Event, key=lambda x: x == None) if not b]`

Comment: OP, can you add in @hilberts_drinking_problem solution to your answer? Else,  @ hilberts_drinking_problem: can you submit this as an answer?

Comment: @Kraigolas feel free to add the vanilla `itertools` solution if you like.